# Ending a while loop when user hits enter, cannot use #include <string.h>

Tags: c, fgets

In this scenario, user input is taken from stdin using fgets. Normally to end a while loop when a user hits enter I would use strcmp between the fgets value and \n, but we are not allowed to use `#include <string.h>` in this particular assignment. Using C99.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `if(*buff == '\n') break;`

Comment: Without `#include` there are no input functions available in the standard.  [Qapla'](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Qapla').

Comment: Sorry, but (IMO) this is a "how to program well" site, not a "help me with my homework" site.  Any 'puzzle' question of the form "Do X, but you're not allowed to use the normal, preferred way of doing X" is therefore unanswerable, partly because X *is* the way to do it if you're looking to program well, and partly because, if these puzzle questions have any value, they have value only if you think about them and figure them out yourself.

Comment: A general reminder to post a [**Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) generally works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, since the `fgets()` function returns when it finds an `\n`

I'm assuming you mean when the user input a single `\n` and nothing else. Itmight be a better idea to use `fgetc()` instead, which will return the `\n`.

This means you need to buffer the inout yourself, something like this:

```
char    inputBuffer[120] = "";

char    ch;
char    chCount = 0;

while (1) {
    ch = fgetc(stdin);

    if (ch == '\n') {
        /* Empty buffer? */
        if (inputBuffer[0] == '\0')
            /* Oui! */
            break;

        /* Buffer isn't empty - do something with it... */
        fprintf(stdout, "Input buffer: %s\n", inputBuffer);

        /* Clear the buffer for the next line of input and reset the
         * counter. */
        inputBuffer[0] = '\0';
        chCount = 0;
    }
    else {
        if (chCount < 119) {
            /* Add the byte to the buffer. */
            inputBuffer[chCount++] = ch;
            inputBuffer[chCount] = '\0';
        }
    }

}
```

The above loop will output any input string or break if a single `\n` is entered.

Comment: Never use a variable declared `char` (as `ch` is here) to hold characters read by `getchar()`, `getc()`, or `fgetc()`.

Comment: Good call, fgetc() returns an int - I stand corrected.